# Voice action can not find my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter, google-now

I am trying to add voice action to my `music app`. When I do the voice action and said:

> Play `Someone like you`

[image]

Google voice search recognized it is a song and it let user chooses what apps to open this intent with (Which include my app). When clicking on my app, I received the sony name as expected.

I noticed that I can say:

> Play `Someone like you` on `Google Music`

[image]

This would let Google voice search open Google Music directly, after a small timeout.

=-=-=

So what is not working is that I can not use `Play [Music] on [My App]`; this would give me a google search result.

[image]

I basically copied my code from [this blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/supporting-new-music-voice-action.html), I wonder if there are anything extra that I have to do in order for `Play [Music] on [My App]` to work?

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="io.github.kylelam.musicvoiceaction" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hello did you managed to make it work ??

Comment: It turns out you just need to wait for a week or two, it mentions some where in the documentation

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any resolution ?

Comment: @GTID you need to let it sit in the app store for a week or 2 for the information to sync into the system... at least it was like it last year.